# Is there any way to extend Outlook express to SMS on incoming mail?

Tags: outlook-express

Is there any way to extend Outlook express to send a SMS notification to my mobile when a new mail comes in so i can then go to the PC and check ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things as per my understanding of your query -
1. You need to send sms from OutLook
2. You need to get alert notifications on your Mobile of upcoming mails in Outlook Inbox

Here are my views, may be you will find solution from these:

1. The one I preferred is SMS Officer go here : http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2008/04/07/introducing-smsofficer.aspx
2. You can configure your mail in your mobile or with the SMS officer you can manage auto SMS-sender through Outlook for every incoming message for your outlook.

Apart from above there are some Ads-on available like : http://www.intellisms.co.uk/sms-gateway/outlook-addin/

There may be some different ways, but till now, I found this one is the best way.

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks. You have mentioned Outlook. Is there a similar way for Outlook Express ?